# My PHP jQuery Contact Form is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My team and I are creating a PHP website for my customer.The issue is my PHP contact form is not sending mail to my customer. My Forms.js is pasted below and Contact.php link is also given. When I hit Submit on my PHP contact form nothing happens and so I don't know what the issue is. I think my same contact form was working before and so I really want someone to look into this and help me...
http://mycustomerhanif.nexia.asia/contact.php
I hope I can get some help and get this form working...
Thank you in advance

```js
$(function() {
  $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mytestmail.php",
      data: formdata
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert("Thank you!");
    }).fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mailsender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
    $name = $_POST['formname'];
    $phone = $_POST['formphone'];
    $email = $_POST['formemail'];
    $xmessage = $_POST['formmessage'];
    
  $to = 'praveen.t@msn.com';
  $subject = 'My Customer Contact';
  $message = '
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Please Contact Me</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                <p><b>Phone:</b> '.$phone.'</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                <p><b>Message:</b> '.$xmessage.'</p>
            </body>
        </html>'; 
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

?>

  <form method="POST" id="contact-form" action="mytestmail.php">
    <section>
      <label class="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="formname" id="formname">
   </label>
      <label class="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="formemail" id="formemail">
   </label>
      <label class="phone">Phone:
      <input type="phone" name="formphone" id="formphone">
   </label>
      <label class="message">Message:
<textarea name="formmessage" id="formmessage"></textarea>
   </label>
      <input id="buttons-reset" name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
      <input id="buttons-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </section>
  </form>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: If you need help with the PHP it needs to be unprocessed code, not a link to a processed page. As @JohnConde said, this question needs to be seriously reworked if you want to get help on SO. Give us a [mcve] of the specific code that isn't working. If you get error messages in PHP or the js console share those as well.

Comment: I have edited my PHP contact and PHP sendmail pages and JS page and so please do have a look...

Comment: You need to add a method to your form:  `<form method="POST" id="contact-form" action="mytestmail.php">` and update your first if statement: `if($_POST['submit']){`

Comment: Thank you I will try now and get back...

Comment: I added POST method in my form and $_POST['submit'] in handler but I am still not getting an email, The thing is I am getting an Ajax thank you from mailsender.js but the actual mail is not getting triggered from my website and I don't know the reason...

Comment: Can you please check my live website and see what can be an issue...

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of bad things in your code.

1. You have the email where you want to send it ['praveen.t@*****.com']
2. You must submit the form values to a server side php, I am not seeing that I only see that you want to send it to usr/sbin/sendmail with is the location of sendmail on the server..

On the point 1, your script can be use for spamming, because they can change the to address.

to send it, just have a form and something like this on the server side.

```
<?php

// please validate upon needed..

$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$to = "mailTO@domain.com";
$subject = 'Some subject';
if(mail ($to,$subject,$message)){
   print "email sent";
}else{
  print "error sending email";
}
?>
```